# Why was the ship "Palmyra" so named?

Tags: united-states, naval, ships

On November 7, 1802, the American trading ship Palmyra, under Captain Cornelius Sawle, was shipwrecked on the reef, which took the vessel's name and now is known as Palmyra Atoll.

Does anybody know the exact reason why the ship itself was named Palmyra? I suppose it was named after some city/town, but I'm not sure. And there are **a lot** of towns and cities named Palmyra, so it's not clear which one is related to the ship.

- Palmyra, Illinois
- Palmyra, Indiana
- Palmyra, an ancient city in Syria
- and so on.

See *[Wikipedia:Palmyra_Disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmyra_(disambiguation))* for a complete list

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing in a ship's registry that requires a reason for a particular name. So, unless the person who named the ship (or possibly re-named the ship) made note of their reasoning and was of sufficient significance to have had that reason retained in the historical record, it can only be a guess. It might be a direct relation with one of the towns with that name or indirect (a relation lived in one) or it just sounded exotic...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure, but I strongly suspect it was named for the historic Palmyra in Syria. Most of the American settlements were only established (or renamed) after 1802 - skimming the WP articles, I get them as GA 1840, IL #1 1855, IL #2 unknown (but almost certainly later), IL #3 1814, IN 1839, ME 1807, MO 1819, NE 1870, NJ 1849, NY 1796, OH #1 1807, OH #2 1835, PA 1806-1810, TN unknown (but [1801 tax records](https://www.tngenweb.org/montgomery/1801tax.htm) mention Palmyra), UT 1852, VA 1814, WI 1846.

So only two of these are old enough to be the namesake of the ship *Palmyra*. But these were both far inland, so not likely to be closely involved with shipping, and neither had had that name for very long, so it was unlikely someone *from* there had moved to the coast, established a business, and named a ship after his hometown.

All the US towns named Palmyra that give a source for the name seem to have adopted it after the Syrian city; presumably it sounded nicely classical and faintly Biblical (even though the name itself isn't in the Bible, the city had associations with Solomon, etc). Given the wave of other things being named after it, it seems very likely this was the source of the name for the ship as well. But, of course, unprovable without a contemporary source.

Comment: A [document](https://books.google.com/books?id=RHTNAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1164&dq=palmyra+ship+1802&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6-N669uHuAhVoFjQIHY-ICXoQuwUwAHoECAUQBw#v=onepage&q=palmyra%20ship%201802&f=false) showing ships registered in Providence RI has a *Palmyra* registered in in 1798. The same page has a *Zenobia* registered in 1795.

Comment: @justCal I think that's almost certainly the same one - [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40475540) mentions *Palmyra* under Sowle returning to Providence after the China voyage in 1803, although oddly it assumes an Atlantic not Pacific route.

Comment: Note that Palmyra, NY was on the Erie canal, so it *was* involved in shipping.  However, the canal was not completed until 1825, so it is still unlikely.

Comment: Lots of places and things named after classical cities back then.  Memphis, Syracuse and Troy spring instantly to mind.

Comment: @RonJohn: In upstate New York, darned near everything that doesn't have a name derived from Indian languages is named after something classical.

Comment: @RonJohn Not to mention Utica, Athens, Alexandria, Cairo

Comment: @jamesqf Really?  Buffalo? Rochester? Albany? Binghamton? Cooperstown?  Newburgh?  Watertown?  Plattsburgh? Champlain?  Jamestown? Lake George?

Comment: @C Monsour: I said "darned near".  Homer, Solon, Cicero,  Marcellus... and of course Rome.

Comment: @C. Monsour Cairo seems to be only a medieval name, though

Comment: [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307123502/http://palmyraarchive.org/items/show/95) paper confirms the ship belonged to Providence, Rhode Island, but there are no further details.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second [Andrew's answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/62819/24512) that it was certainly *ultimately* from the [ancient Syrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syria_(region)) (≠Syria) town of [Palmyra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmyra) that served as [Rome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Empire)'s entrepôt for [Persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthian_Empire) goods[¹](https://www.jstor.org/stable/298363) and thus part of the trail end of the overland [Silk Road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk_Road) connecting [Antioch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antioch) to [Chang'an](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27an) in [Han China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Han_Empire). (The *actual* border town was [Dura-Europus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dura-Europus) but that name is *much* clunkier and never became a popular one for ships or US towns.)

[image: Silk Road 0.1]
*Palmyra is that place where the route splits between Antioch and Damascus*

It probably was directly named for the city as well. This ship was out of and owned by residents of [Providence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Providence,_Rhode_Island), [Rhode Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhode_Island),[²](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LraODwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13)[³](https://books.google.com/books?id=QPlTEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20-IA13)[⁴](https://books.google.com/books?id=4QgQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22palmyra%22+%22sowle%22) and intended—like many non-whaling New England ships of its era—for the [Old China Trade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_China_Trade). It was en route to [Guangzhou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guangzhou) ("Canton") at the time it passed the atoll,[⁵](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LraODwAAQBAJ&pg=PA11) the [First Opium War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Opium_War) not having opened up any of the other [treaty ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/treaty_ports) yet and China still imposing a form of the [Ming *haijin*](https://en.wikipedia/wiki/haijin) ("sea ban") after a brief period of greater openness at the onset of the [Qing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty). I don't see any direct statements from the owners—e.g. from the Rhode Island Historical Society—but the city was very famous at the time as an [exotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientalism) free agent connecting the commerce of empires, suiting the ship perfectly. [William Pitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Pitt_the_Younger)'s niece went out her way to visit,[⁶](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/the-insouciant-heiress-who-became-the-first-western-woman-to-enter-palmyra) it shows up in Shelley's [*Last Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Man),[⁷](https://thegothicwanderer.wordpress.com/tag/lord-byron/) and Romantic readers ate up the story of its tragic queen [Zenobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenobia).[⁸](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/8938/8938-h/8938-h.htm) Yes, it absolutely sucks that it's most well known now for having been destroyed.[⁹](https://www.wilsonquarterly.com/quarterly/_/what-we-lost-in-palmyra) If it wasn't directly from the ancient city, it's more likely for one of the numerous *other* American, British, and Dutch ships that were.

Note that the US Navy at least mistakenly derived the island's name from [palmyra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borassus_flabellifer), a species of palm whose name is owed to [Portuguese *palmeira*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palmeira#Portuguese) by an [entirely separate derivation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palmyra#Etymology).[¹⁰](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ChyilRml0hcC&pg=PA47)